# Apps built with Xcode 6 don't run on iOS8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I recently updated to *Xcode 6 beta 3*.

When I run my app in *Xcode 6 beta 2* it runs fine. When I run my app in *beta 3* on an `iOS7` device it runs fine.

However, when I run using *beta 3* and `iOS8` *beta 3*, it builds, claims it is running (in the toolbar feedback); and – about 5 seconds after that – it shows *"finished running"* in the toolbar. The app isn't installed on the phone after all this. There isn't anything logged in the console. Everything from *Xcode*'s side appears fine.

I did manage to install the app the first two times I tried, but never again.

I used a work around [invalid virtual filesystem overlay file](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/234786?start=0&tstart=0) when the error mentioned in link popped up... but I'm not sure how that is related to this.

I reset everything I can think of, and reinstalled `iOS8` on the phone. Nothing seems to fix this problem. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Having the same problem on Beta 7.

Comment: You should use XCode 6.0. Not beta version.

Comment: This was in July. The only xCode 6 available was the beta system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fixed in later xCode versions.