# SwiftyDropbox errors after installation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to install SwiftyDropbox via cocoapods. After successful installation, I open .xcworkspace file, and see two errors:

```
invalid virtual filesystem overlay file 
'/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DropTest-gzupfdtcnnwgfoghucwjowoivskc/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyDropbox.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml
```

and

```
clang importer creation failed
```

My podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do
  pod 'SwiftyDropbox'
end
```

I've tried to delete project folder in DerivedData with no luck.

The sample project from Dropbox's github repo works fine.

Cocoapods version: 1.0.1

Xcode version: 7.3.1

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206989466-SwiftyDropbox-errors-after-installation ]

This may not be specific to SwiftyDropbox. There are some existing posts that may be helpful though:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622650/xcode-6-beta-3-invalid-virtual-filesystem-overlay-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684100/apps-built-with-xcode-6-dont-run-on-ios8
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381933/invalid-virtual-filesystem-overlay-file-i-tried-everything